# Google Analytic Cohort Report

Tags: google-analytics, analysis

Is there a way to import data (from external file, DB, API, webhock or whatever other method) into Google Analytics to be used as dimensions and Metric on the Google Analytics Cohort Report?

The case is that I get paid customers data only few weeks after their visit/registration on the site, from a 3rd party payment processor and I want to load that data onto the Cohort report.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Analytics Data Import](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3191589?hl=en) to import user data, you can even do it programmatically through the [Google Analytics Management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtDataImport#user).

To query cohorts with respect to the first date of session, you should use the segment date of [session syntax](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/segments#dateOfSession-example): 
Select users who have had their first session between May 20, 2014 and May 30, 2014 and have spent > 600 seconds on the site.

```
segment=users::sequence::^ga:sessionCount==1;dateOfSession<>2014-05-20_2014-05-30;->>ga:sessionDurationBucket>600
```

But there is no reason why you could not create a segment from an imported user custom dimensions. In fact here is a good example of [using data import to create AdWords remarketing lists](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/data-import-user).